# Mapbox React Native accessing map method

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

I am using [Mapbox](https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl) in React Native and the documentation of the [MapboxGL.MapView](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/docs/MapView.md) object lists several methods, but I am unable to use them. For example, `getVisibleBounds()` is said to work like this:

> `const visibleBounds = await this._map.getVisibleBounds();`

I have implemented it like this:

```
<View style={container}>
    <Mapbox.MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        styleJSON={JSON.stringify(defaultStyle)}
        zoomLevel={16}
        centerCoordinate={[lat, lng]}
        onRegionDidChange={onRegionDidChange}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
    </Mapbox.MapView>
</View>
```

The `onRegionDidChange` function is defined as:

```
const mapRef = useRef();

const onRegionDidChange = async () => {
    try {
        const currentBounds = await mapRef.getVisibleBounds();
        console.log(currentBounds);
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }
};
```

Doing this gives:  `mapRef.getVisibleBounds is not a function.`

The map itself works fine, I guess I am just unsure of the correct way to use the function. I have also tried using `this._map.getVisibileBounds()`, but this gives:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.map.getVisibleBounds')`

I have seen similar questions asked on here and Github, however they are either unanswered or outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out by using the [examples](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/tree/main/example) provided in the documentation.

I used a class component, then the `ref` in `MapView` should be specified as `ref={c => (this._map = c)}` like this:

```
<Mapbox.MapView
    ref={c => (this._map = c)}
    styleJSON={JSON.stringify(defaultStyle)}
    zoomLevel={16}
    centerCoordinate={[lat, lng]}
    onRegionDidChange={this.onRegionDidChange}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
>
```

And finally bind `this` to your function in the class constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.onRegionDidChange = this.onRegionDidChange.bind(this);
}
```

The method itself is defined as follows:

```
async onRegionDidChange() {
    try {
        const currentBounds = await this._map.getVisibleBounds();
        console.log(currentBounds);
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

Edit: for a functional component, just create a variable `let mapRef = null;` and specify the ref as: `ref={(c) => (mapRef = c)}` then the function as:

```
let getBounds = async () => {
    try {
        const bounds = await map.getVisibleBounds();
        console.log(bounds);
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: You cant use refs without a class component??